# Can i use route inside a controller in express js?

Tags: javascript, express, routes, controller

So I have something like this in one of my controllers:

```js
module.exports.authToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.cookies.jwt;
    //console.log(token);
    if (!token) {
        return res.sendStatus(403);
    }
    try {
        const data = jwt.verify(token, "secret token");
        console.log(data);
        req.userId = data.id;
        return next();
      } catch {
        return res.sendStatus(403);
      }
  };
```

and it's called by a route:

```js
router.get("/protected", authController.authToken, (req, res) => {
    return res.json({ user: { id: req.userId, role: req.userRole } });
  });
```

and I want to get a JSON response of that route in one of my other controllers. I tried some things but none of it worked.

Comment: estas intentando crear un middleware para que el cliente que haga una consulta a esa ruta este autorizado si o si ?

Comment: yes I want to check if the user is logged in

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is abstract the response out to a function for re-use:

```js
// the function will just return the data without writing it to the response
function protectedRoute(req) {
    return {user: {id: req.userId, role: req.userRole}};
}

router.get("/protected", authController.authToken, (req, res) => {
    // in the actual handler you can return the response
    return res.json(protectedRoute(req));
});

// make sure the middleware is still being run
router.get("/other_route", authController.authToken, (req, res) => {
    // use the same function to get the response from /protected
    const protectedResponse = protectedRoute(req);
    // do stuff with it
});
```

Comment: ok, but can I do that my other route calls another controller, and inside this controller get data to a variable like if I used /protected route?